# how to apply script on specific sheets within a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

**script (attempt):**

```
function moveValuesOnly() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange('P1!B10');
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange('P1!B11'), {contentsOnly: true}); }

function moveValuesOnly() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange('P2!B10');
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange('P2!B11'), {contentsOnly: true}); }

function moveValuesOnly() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange('P3!B10');
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange('P3!B11'), {contentsOnly: true}); }

function moveValuesOnly() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange('D1!B10');
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange('D1!B11'), {contentsOnly: true}); }

function moveValuesOnly() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange('D2!B10');
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange('D2!B11'), {contentsOnly: true}); }

function moveValuesOnly() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange('D3!B10');
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange('D3!B11'), {contentsOnly: true}); }

function moveValuesOnly() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange('P!B10');
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange('P!B11'), {contentsOnly: true}); }
```

in one spreadsheet I have these sheets `"P1, P2, P3, ..., P"` and in every sheet I have a button. next, I need to achieve that if I am in let's say sheet **D1** and press button in that sheet a script will execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it...

```
function moveValuesOnly1() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange("P1!B10");
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange("P1!B11"), {contentsOnly: true}); }

function moveValuesOnly2() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange("P2!B10");
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange("P2!B11"), {contentsOnly: true}); }

function moveValuesOnly3() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange("P3!B10");
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange("P3!B11"), {contentsOnly: true}); }

function moveValuesOnly4() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange("D1!B10");
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange("D1!B11"), {contentsOnly: true}); }

function moveValuesOnly5() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange("D2!B10");
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange("D2!B11"), {contentsOnly: true}); }

function moveValuesOnly6() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange("D3!B10");
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange("D3!B11"), {contentsOnly: true}); }

function moveValuesOnly7() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange('P!B10');
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange('P!B11'), {contentsOnly: true}); }
```